# Is there a way to show the mobile keyboard while using Expo Web

Tags: react-native, expo

I'm developing an app using react native with expo - is there a way I can test out the mobile keyboard and how it'll affect the layout of the app while using Expo Web (so developing in my browser and not mobile phone)

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

You can try out creating a snack on expo on browser, it having IOS and android device simulator that you can get instant review for your develop apps